# Access is denied:'cplex.egg-info' , what should I do?

Tags: python, anaconda, cplex

I would like to set up a virtual environment to use python cplex library on windows. I have installed python version 3.7 and CPLEX studio201.win-x86-64

When I use the code: python setup.py install
It was error as in the screenshot. Could anyone help, please? Thank you in advance.

[image: Screenshot from Anaconda Prompt (anaconda3)]
[image: Initial Step]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
python setup.py install --user
```